# Can setContentView be replaced by android-annotations when espresso is used?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-annotations

I have espresso test which verifies that text is displayed:

```
public class InformationActivityTests {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<InformationActivity_> mInformationActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<InformationActivity_>(InformationActivity_.class) {
                @Override
                protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getTargetContext(), InformationActivity_.class);
                    i.putExtra("INFORMATION", "Espresso");
                    return i;
                }
            };

    @Test
    public void textIsDisplayed() {
        onView(withText("Espresso")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

This test **passes** when Activity has following code:

```
@EActivity
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @ViewById(R.id.information_view)
    TextView informationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String information = intent.getStringExtra("INFORMATION");
        informationView.setText(information);
    }
}
```

but **fails** when I "move" setContentView to @EActivity annotation:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_information)
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @ViewById(R.id.information_view)
    TextView informationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String information = intent.getStringExtra("INFORMATION");
        informationView.setText(information);
    }
}
```

Error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edu/com.edu.InformationActivity_}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Am I doing something wrong or is it an issue with espresso / android-annotations?

Comment: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/1009#issuecomment-43714777 this answer suggests using  `@AfterViews` annotation on a method with  view configuration. I have no experience with android-annotations thought.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Actually your answer is better than mine, so feel free to post it and I will accept.

Comment: your investigation makes more sense for a complete answer, so post what worked and accept your own answer ;)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked code generated by android-annotations when using @EActivity(R.layout.activity_information) and this is how onCreate looks like in generated class (InformationActivity_):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    OnViewChangedNotifier previousNotifier = OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(onViewChangedNotifier_);
    init_(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(previousNotifier);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);
}
```

the problem is that it first calls **super.onCreate** (so onCreate from InformationActivity) where I handle intent and TextView and then it calls **setContentView** and this can't work like that.

The solution for this is what [Be_Negative](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879701/be-negative) suggested, so using @AfterViews annotation. It also simplifies code a bit (I could remove onCreate method):

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_information)
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @ViewById(R.id.information_view)
    TextView informationView;

    @AfterViews
    void handleIntent() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String information = intent.getStringExtra("INFORMATION");
        informationView.setText(information);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are never initializing informationview

```
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@ViewById(R.id.information_view)
TextView informationView; //<-- Null

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String information = intent.getStringExtra("INFORMATION");
    informationView.setText(information); //<--STILL NULL
}
}
```

So you first will have to initialize that view.

Comment: No, it is initialized by @ViewById. If you would be right then test would fail also in first case.